# How can I keep elements aligned despite screen size?

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to programming at all and was just wondering how I could keep elements in their place no matter the screen size of the user. More specifically, how I could keep a list aligned at the top from pushing to the next line when the user changes the width of the screen. I've looked for a while for the answer but just haven't been able to find anything; could be that I just don't know what to search for.
Here is my code for the CSS portion of the list:

```
li {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 2px 4px 3px 4px;
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
display: table-cell;
display: fixed;
background-color: 362C24;
```

}

Comment: Please post your code, what you've tried and try to give us a better description of the problem. There are probably lots of ways to achieve what you want, but nothing that is general and will work all the time for any cases.

Comment: The problem is that when I shorten the width of the screen size, it just pushes the list of items that are aligned at the top to the next line down. What I want it to do is to just keep the list fixed there and allow the screen size to change with no change to the appearance of the page. I've tried to do some things on display and position like making it absolute and giving a table-cell display. As I said, I'm fairly new so my base of things to try isn't very broad.

Comment: Please don't tag the editor you're using unless you have a question about it. Nobody cares.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Static Positioning (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), but I don't think that's what you want to do when your programming for responsive design. You could use flex-box(https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but if there's not space for something it's going to be positioned accordingly. Everyone is looking on a different size screen, you want to accommodate everyone. Fixing things in absolute places might be ok for desktop, but with the wide array of viewport sizes, I don't recommend it.